# How to trick Node.js to load .js files as ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Node.JS 10 added experimental support for loading ES6 modules, which already work in browsers. That would mean that we could finally use exactly the same files for Node.JS and browsers without any transpiling or polyfills.

Except we can't. Node.js requires `.mjs` extension for files to be loaded as modules. I tried tricking node by using a symlink, but node got around it:

```
D:\web\lines>node --experimental-modules ES6test.mjs
(node:7464) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
D:\web\lines\ES6test.js:6
import myLibrary from "./MyFile.mjs";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can't think of any other workaround to make this work - which really renders the whole ES6 module support useless.

Can anybody else think of some trick to make Node.js ignore the extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now import `.js` file in node **v12.x**, in 2 steps:

- Add the following line in your `package.json` file:

```js
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

- Add `--experimental-modules` flag **before** the script:

```sh
node --experimental-modules index.js
```

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: I followed you, but still got the same error.
node version is 12.19.0

Comment: I have done fixings using: node  --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js

Answer (score 4):

Node.js requires all ES modules should have .mjs extension. Since Node.js support of ES modules is experimental, this is subject to change. [A proposal](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/pull/60) and open [pull request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/18392) are expected to address this problem with package.json `esm` flag  and `--mode` option.

Currently this can be solved with custom [ES module loader](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_loader_hooks) that hooks into default module resolver and changes module type for some modules:

*custom-loader.mjs*

```
import path from 'path';

const ESM_WITH_JS_EXT = './MyFile.js'; // relative to loader path
const ESM_WITH_JS_EXT_URL = new URL(path.dirname(import.meta.url) + `/${ESM_WITH_JS_EXT}`).href;

export function resolve(specifier, parentModuleURL, defaultResolver) {
    const resolvedModule = defaultResolver(specifier, parentModuleURL);

    if (resolvedModule.url === ESM_WITH_JS_EXT_URL)
        resolvedModule.format = 'esm';

    return resolvedModule;
}
```

It is used as:

```
node --experimental-modules --loader ./custom-loader.mjs ./index.mjs
```

Since there are fundamental differences in how ES and CommonJS modules are evaluated, the changes should be limited to modules that need them.

Comment: Looks promising, I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

I solved exactly this problem with the fabulous [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) package. You can enable dynamic (smart) esm module loading package wide, or per run with a flag like this:

```
node -r esm your/es6/module.js
```

It also has options to treat every file as a es6 module, or only those ending in '.mjs'. There are other packages out there, but this one just worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Import and export modules using ES6 that work with Node.js

Name files with `.mjs` extension instead of `.js`

#### Create files

```
touch main.mjs lib.mjs
```

#### main.js

```
import { add } from './lib.mjs';
console.log(add(40, 2));
```

#### lib.mjs

```
export let add = (x,y) => {
  return x + y
}
```

#### Run

```
node --experimental-modules main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module that does what you need `esmjs.mjs`

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from 'url'
import { dirname, join } from 'path'

export const jsmodule = (test_url_or_path, module_path) => {

    const __filename = test_url_or_path.toLowerCase().startsWith('file:')
        ? fileURLToPath(test_url_or_path)
        : test_url_or_path

    const __dirname = dirname(__filename)

    const abs_path = join(__dirname, module_path)
    const file_url = pathToFileURL(abs_path)

    const file_buf = readFileSync(file_url)
    const b64 = file_buf.toString('base64')

    const moduleData = "data:text/javascript;base64," + b64

    return import(moduleData)
}
```

Usage from `.mjs` module:

```js
const { hey } = await jsmodule(import.meta.url, '../../test-data/mjs.js')
```

Usage, from `.js` file:

```js
const { hey } = await jsmodule(__filename, '../../test-data/mjs.js')
```

[Reference & tests on Github](https://github.com/devmachiine/t3st/tree/1e8bb49ae6811797ab513df48a728e8449b163c4/tests/commands)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way:

Create a file module2.mjs (the name is up to you)

```
'use strict';

export function foo() {
    return 'foo';
}
```

Create index.mjs file:

```
'use strict';

import { foo } from './module2.mjs';

console.log(foo());
```

Using node 8.11.1 (or 10) you can run it as (command and output provided):

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
(node:60428) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
foo
```

Comment: I assume that that the goal is to import existing .js ES modules (a package or common code) without changing their extensions to .mjs.

Comment: then i guess is not possible, at least with node native function, if babel is an option then I guess could be possible

Comment: I found it to be possible but hacky, see my answer.